# sudo works, but gksudo doesn't, why?

Tags: 12.04, sudo, quickly, python-2.7, gksudo

```
sudo lshw -html>1.html
```

works perfectly.I get system information in 1.html.

But,

```
gksudo lshw -html>1.html
```

doesn't work.I get `gksudo` usage options in 1.html

Information:
I am developing an app in `Quickly`.I need that my user
will have to enter password in a graphical prompt in 
order to generate a system information report.But

```
os.system('gksudo lshw -html>1.html')
```

is not working.What is the solution?

EDIT:
One solution found in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1462426

```
gksudo -- lshw -html>1.html
```

But what is the significance of `--`?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is used for running command line utilities whereas `gksudo` is used for running graphical utilities.

While you can run the other with both these commands, it is not advisable to do so. Since `lshw` is a command line utility, it will work best with `sudo`.

Also, in the link that you've mentioned, one of the person has posted the use of `--`.

> it tells the app to stop reading options. Without it, gksudo will treat any argument starting with a - as an option to gksudo. When it encounters --, all arguments following will no longer be treated as options to gksudo, and just passed on to the child process.